# Haskell: How to check that a char is valid utf8

Tags: haskell, utf-8

How do I check that a `Char` in haskell is a valid UTF8 codepoint?

I have a class that is generating strings, subject to some set of constraints, and an `Arbitrary` instance of that class (that generates only strings that satisfy these constraints).  I'm using `GenValidity` with this.  But the standard generator for String is generating occasional invalid characters; such as `'\xed'`.  Unsurprisingly, this causes issues later.

By 'invalid', I mean that `Data.Text.Encoding.streamDecodeUtf8` flags an error:

```
λ> streamDecodeUtf8 (Data.ByteString.Char8.pack "\xed")
Some "" "\237" _
```

I'd like to add a constraint to my GenValidity instance that is based on a (hypothetical) `isValidUTF8 :: Char -> Bool` function, but surprisingly, I can find nothing to match.  The best I can do atm is

```
((\ (Data.Text.Encoding.Some _ x _) -> x /= "") . Data.Text.Encoding.streamDecodeUtf8With (\ _ _ -> Nothing) . Data.ByteString.Char8.pack) . pure
```

Which is surely rather heavyweight, and I worry that conversions to ByteString, then to Text, could introduce sharp edges.

I'm surprised that I can't find anything better/pre-canned.

Advice and pointers welcomed!

Comment: I am not sure to understand the requirement. UTF8 is just one of the byte renditions of Unicode. Haskell Char objects are Unicode points. A String generator has every right to include a character whose numeric code is 0xED=237,that is the i acute 'í'. You might want to have a go at evaluating under ghci: `GHC.Unicode.isPrint $ chr(237)`  and  `putStrLn $ ((chr 237):"")`  Of course, at the start of the Unicode forbidden range, `isPrint $ chr 55296` returns False.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure where I got '\xed' from, - that was brain fade.  It should've been '\xda65'.  Though I'm no longer sure that that's an invalid char, either. Certainly my unhappy example fn doesn't flag it as invalid.

Comment: Actually, I found it, and revised the question to match.  The underlying issue is with Data.Text.Encoding.streamDecodeUtf8, which seems to think that `'\xed'` is bad.

Comment: As far as UTF-8 is concerned, `\xed` is an incomplete sequence. You cannot generate an arbitrary sequence of bytes and hope that it will be a valid UTF-8 string. If there is a problem at the producer side, then weeding out invalid strings at the consumer side can take forever; you better fix the producer.

Comment: Expression `isPrint $ chr (read "0xda65")` returns False, that's in the invalid D800-DFFF range. You might have to filter the production of your generator at the Char/String level.

Comment: Ah yes, you are both right - thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those examples work as expected.

The question "How to check that a `Char` is valid UTF-8" makes no sense (but you can't be blamed for not knowing what you don't know). It is based on a misunderstanding of what UTF-8 is. UTF-8 is an encoding: it describes one way to turn those codepoints into bytes, which can be stored or sent over the network.

To make an analogy, this is like asking "How to check that an `Integer` is valid base 10". Think about why that makes no sense.

An *encoding* is a property of "concrete data" like "bytestrings" (sequences of bytes, this is the `ByteString` types in Haskell). Once those bytes have been decoded, we have just "text", and UTF-8 is no longer a relevant concept at that level of abstraction (sequences of codepoints (`Char`), this is `Text` or `String` in Haskell).

> But the standard generator for String is generating occasional invalid characters; such as '\xed'.

All `Char`s are valid[1] Unicode codepoints. ([See the doc.](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Char.html#t:Char)) `'\xed'` is codepoint number 237.

[1]: for some definition of "valid"... Unicode conceals a lot of complexity.

> By 'invalid', I mean that `Data.Text.Encoding.streamDecodeUtf8` flags an error:
>
> ```
> λ> streamDecodeUtf8 (Data.ByteString.Char8.pack "\xed")
> Some "" "\237" _
> ```

`streamDecodeUtf8` is meant to be applied to UTF-8 bytestrings, but `Data.ByteString.Char8.pack` does not produce UTF-8. `Char8.pack` is more of a hack to emulate bytestring literals; it abuses Unicode to work around the fact that in Haskell, there are only literals for Unicode strings. But here you don't want to generate arbitrary bytes, so don't use `Char8.pack`.

To encode text, use one of [the encoding functions from the `Data.Text.Encoding` module](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.4.0/docs/Data-Text-Encoding.html#v:encodeUtf8). As we can see, there are different functions for different encodings, which further illustrates the above point that "encoding" is not a property inherent to text, but has to do with its representation in memory (which `ByteString` exposes).

```
ghci> import Data.Text (pack)
ghci> import Data.Text.Encoding
ghci> streamDecodeUtf8 (encodeUtf8 (Data.Text.pack "\xed"))
Some "\237" "" _
```

> I'm surprised that I can't find anything better/pre-canned.

There are many complaints to be had about text in Haskell and programming at large, but in this case the question stems from a misunderstanding of Unicode. The fault is not on you, this system is certainly not obvious if you're not already familiar with it.

Comment: Thank you @Li-yao Xia.  I am embarrassed that I really should know most of that, but I am grateful for the reminder and very clear explanation, as I had forgotten some bits and gotten it round my neck.  What you say makes good sense, and indeed, I was trying to generate valid strings from random bytes; and when we step back, that is indeed a nonsense.  I'm glad I asked, this has saved me a great deal of time and bother trying to solve the wrong problem.